# Why doesn't CMake add the "GENERATED" property to file created by "configure_file"?

Tags: c++, cmake

The CMake [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) command can be used to create concrete files from templates. Calling `configure_file(foo.h.in foo.h)` will generate the `foo.h` file which did not existed prior to running `cmake`.

Yet, it's not marked with the [`GENERATED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/GENERATED.html) property. Calling `get_source_file_property(is_generated foo.h GENERATED)` returns `NOTFOUND`.

What is the rational behind this behavior that I'm missing?

Comment: `GENERATED` are files which are created during the **build stage**, but `configure_file` creates a file immediately, on **configuration stage**. Also you could treat GENERATED files as ones which could be removed without needs to re-configure the project. But after removing result of `configure_file` the project cannot be built without re-configuration.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The `GENERATED` docs states "Is this source file generated as part of the build or CMake process", isn't `configure_file()` part of the CMake process / configuration stage?

Comment: Not sure what they mean by "CMake process". In other paragraph they say "The Makefile Generators will remove `GENERATED` files during `make clean`." but I see no reason to remove result of `configure_file` upon `make clean`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yeah, it's a bit weird. They also mention `file(GENERATE)` as being marked as `GENERATED` yet it's created during configuration and not build stage.

Comment: At least, when you check the file created with `file(GENERATE)` in `CMakeLists.txt`, it is **not created yet**: the file is created only at the end of configuration process. But `configure_file` creates the file **immediately**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for explaining the difference. That's certainly what they mean by "CMake process". Also, as you said, it's pretty clear that `GENERATED` is designed for files created at build time according to the comment: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21993#note_928960 
Docs are a bit confusing in my opinion but it's OK. Feel free to answer this question given your explanation so I can accept it (I would do it as community answer otherwise). ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation, the purpose of a source file's property [GENERATED](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/GENERATED.html) is to prevent checking of the file during configuration process:

> This information is then used to exempt the file from any existence or validity checks.

E.g. `add_executable` command could emit an error if one of its source files does not exist at the time of configuration. This check could reveal problems before one attempts to build the configured project.

But marked with `GENERATED` file is not checked until the build stage.

Because `configure_file` creates the file immediately, it is perfectly correct to check the file's existence when this file is used for e.g. `add_executable` call.
That is, there is no reason to mark this file as GENERATED.

---

The first paragraph in the property's documentation

> Is this source file generated as part of the build or CMake process.

looks controversial, as `configure_file` creates the file during the "CMake process".

Probably, by noting "CMake process" they wanted to fit that `file(GENERATE)` actually sets that property. But there is fundamental difference between `configure_file` and `file(GENERATE)` about a file's generation time:

- `configure_file` creates the file **immediately**, before CMake would execute the next command in `CMakeLists.txt`.
- but `file(GENERATE)` creates the file only **at the end** of configuration process, after all `CMakeLists.txt` are processed.